# Standard way to define parameter-less function main() in C

Tags: c

What is the correct way, according to the latest C standard, to define functions without parameters: `int main()` or `int main(void)`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Both forms of **definition** are valid (the one without `void` is an invalid **prototype** and an *incomplete (albeit valid) **declaration***).

The form `int main(void) { /* whetever */ }` also provides a prototype for the function.
The form `int main() { /* whatever */ }` does not provide a prototype (and the compiler cannot check if it is called correctly).

See [the Standard (PDF)](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf)

> 6.7.5.3/14
>
> An empty list in a function declarator that is part of a deﬁnition of that function speciﬁes that the function has no parameters.

difference between **definition**: `int main() { /* whatever */ }`
and **declaration**: `int main();`
and **prototype**: `int main(void);`.

The *definition* does not provide a prototype;
the *declaration* is valid but specifies no information about the number or types of parameters;
the *prototype* is ok and compatible with the definition.