# What argv = NULL means?

Tags: c

I'm trying to make arguments information umodifiable.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(const int argc, const char* const argv[]) {
  //argc = 1;         // error: assignment of read-only parameter 'argc'
  //argv[0] = "argv"; // error: assignment of read-only location '*argv'
  //argv[0][0] = 'a'; // error: assignment of read-only location '**argv'
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Now when I do this,

```c
argv = NULL; // no compile-time error
```

the compiler makes silence.

What does the statement actually do?
How can I prohibit my codes from doing that?

Comment: Arguments are already unmodifiable.. They're passed to your application from the command line using `argv`, and `argc` indicates the number that were passed. You don't have to do anything to make them unmodifiable except to stop writing code that tries to do so. IOW, if you stop writing code like `argv =`, you won't have any problems.

Comment: @KenWhite "Arguments are already unmodifiable", this is false, you are allowed to change it.

Comment: You have answers, but they're missing it's **not a good idea at all**. The C standard only describes two valid forms for main: `int main(void)` and `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`. `int main(int argc, char **argv)` is 100% equivalent because of type adjustment rules, therefore ok as well, but if you start adding `const`, it's a **different signature**. Implementations of C are allowed to support other forms of main they define themselves, but your program no longer conforms to standard C, another compiler could reject it.

Comment: @FelixPalmen I've never known that. Is it true that putting `const`s makes ***different signature***? Thanks.

Comment: @FelixPalmen: The two `const`s in `const char* const argv[]` are definitely nonstandard, but off the top of my head, I don't recall whether making `argc` or `argv` themselves `const` is nonstandard.

Comment: @JinKwon see a standard document (e.g. http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf, the latest draft to C11) -- §5.1.2.2.1 desribes `main` and e.g. §6.7.6.1 p2 tells you why `const char **` and `char **` are **not compatible**.

Comment: @user2357112 by *themselves*, you mean like `int main(const argc, char ** argv const)`? I **guess** that would be allowed as it doesn't change how the function can be called **at all** (and it's IMHO utterly pointless, just making your local variable `const`).

Comment: What's with all the downvotes? It's a good question?

Comment: @FelixPalmen: incompatible means no silent conversion (6.5.16.1p1) but 'same representation and alignment' (6.2.5p26,28) are 'meant to imply interchangeability' in several (admittedly nonnormative) footnotes. Since `main` must be callable from C as well as the automatic call from the environment, I believe the last sentence of 6.7.6.3p15 allows top-level `const`

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I'm on mobile right now, so can't look up the text ... are you saying there's a guarantee in the standard that a pointer to const has the same internal representation as the corresponding pointer to non-const? In this case, yes, it should work (might be an interesting discussion in language-lawyer). I'd still say don't do it, if only to avoid confusion...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since this answer has been pinned to the top, I feel I should point out that my answer only addresses part of the issue. See [Felix Palmen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50083766/) for why not to declare `main` this way.

---

If a parameter is declared with an array type, the type is implicitly replaced with a pointer type:

```
int main(const int argc, const char* const argv[]) {
```

becomes

```
int main(const int argc, const char* const *argv) {
```

so `argv` is a non-const pointer to const pointer to const char.

`argv = NULL` simply sets that pointer to a null pointer, just like assigning NULL to any other pointer. This won't have any directly visible external effect - it won't erase your command line or anything - but it will interfere with further attempts to use argument information from within your program.

If you want `argv` itself to be const, declare it as const:

```
int main(const int argc, const char * const * const argv) {
```

Comment: Could be write `int main(int const argc, char const * const * const argv)`, however there is not a consensus about what syntax use.

Comment: I like writing `const char *const *const argv` because `*const` acts like a unit ("const pointer"). It's almost like a subscript on `*`.

Comment: @chqrlie No, I don't. I realize my choices are mine alone, but please don't tell me what I "really mean".

Comment: @melpomene: sorry for my poor choice of terms. I personally prefer to underscore what `const` applies to this way: `char const* const* const argv`

Answer (score 10):

Well, first of all, **don't do it**.

I refer to existing answers for *how* you would do it, they explain the different levels `const` can be applied and how to write it in [straight pointer syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50083458/2371524) as well as in ["disguised as an array"-syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50083456/2371524). That's definitely good to know.

But here it comes: `main` is very special. According to the C standard, it doesn't have a prototype, but the definition should take one of two forms only. Here's the original text, from [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), the latest draft to C11:

**§ 5.1.2.2.1**:

> The function called at program startup is named `main`. The implementation declares no
>   prototype for this function. It shall be defined with a return type of `int` and with no
>   parameters:
>   `int main(void) { /* ... */ }`
>   or with two parameters (referred to here as `argc` and `argv`, though any names may be
>   used, as they are local to the function in which they are declared):
>   `int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { /* ... */ }`
>   or equivalent;<sup>10)</sup> or in some other implementation-defined manner.

The footnote 10 even explains what *equivalent* means here:

> Thus, `int` can be replaced by a typedef name defined as `int`, or the type of `argv` can be written as
>   `char ** argv`, and so on.

But as for adding some `const`s, look for example at **§ 6.7.6.1 p2**:

> For two pointer types to be compatible, both shall be **identically qualified** and both shall
>   be pointers to compatible types.

(emphasis mine). `const` is a type qualifier. So `const char **` is **not** compatible with `char **`. You define a `main` that doesn't conform to the C standard any more. Therefore, just don't do it. Use `const` correctness inside your program, but don't try changing the interface for program startup.

---

Side note: exactly the **one** `const` you're asking about here **might** be ok, because it applies to the pointer itself, which is just a local variable to the function (as parameters are always *by value* in C function calls). So it doesn't change the function's interface. That's why in practice, nobody bothers adding such `const`s. It's not important for calling code whether a function modifies its locals or not.

Answer (score 6):

You can put `const` in the brackets of an array-looking pointer parameter to prevent reassignment to it:

```
int main(const int argc, const char* const argv[const]) {
```

People don’t typically bother with this.

Comment: I'm still not sure why they bothered putting in this syntax. C's declaration syntax is confusing enough without it, and as far as I can tell, it doesn't add new functionality or make anything easier.

Comment: @user2357112: It needs to be available if you want to use both `const` and `[static n]`, I think.

Comment: This doesn't help if one does [as many programs do]: `parse_my_options(&argc,&argv)`. And, I believe I read somewhere where the correct definition(s) is/are: `int main(int argc,char **argv)` or `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc,char **argv,char **envp)`. Others will work, but they're not considered idiomatic. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12146594/definition-of-main-in-c

Comment: @CraigEstey: Doesn’t help how? You get a const pointer from `&argv`.

Comment: @CraigEstey This have nothing to do with idiom, the standard only say that any other definition of main will be implemented behavior. But it's true that main argument have no reason to be `const` because we often use them to handle option. As in [`getopt()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getopt.3.html), this function change the order of pointer in `*argv`.

Comment: Huh. I was not aware of the `[static n]` thing. [Looks like](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.6.3p7) it's a way to say that a pointer must point to the start of an at-least-n-element array (which has confusing implications if you pass a pointer that points into the middle of an array).

Comment: From the C standard [1999], 5.1.2.2.1: _The  parameters argc and argv and  the  strings  pointed  to  by  the argv
array  shall be  **modifiable**  by  the  program,  and  retain  their  last-stored  values  between  program startup and program termination._ So, adding `const` sort of defeats the intended purpose.

Comment: @user2357112 "which has confusing implications if you pass a pointer that points into the middle of an array" it's a pointer anyway, there no way to pass an array to a function in C. So you just need to pass a pointer where that address a contigus `n` numbers of element. So it could be a pointer to the middle of an array. More information about effect of [static] [What is the purpose of static keyword in array parameter of function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430315/what-is-the-purpose-of-static-keyword-in-array-parameter-of-function-like-char#3430353.)

Comment: @Stargateur: The standard specifically requires the pointer to point to the *start* of an array. If I declare `int f(int a[static 2])` and `int x[3]` and call `f(x+1)`, it's quite confusing whether or not that call is valid.

Comment: @user2357112 Well... standard often use array and contigus element interchangeably... This is one point where the standard really sux. But you can easily see with [this](http://rextester.com/NBWXZ45522) example that it's not an array ;). The only and very useful warning produce is: "sizeof on array function parameter will return size of 'char *' instead of 'char [static 100]' [-Wsizeof-array-argument]" ;). To conclude when the standard say array, it's often mean contigus element.

Comment: If you are going to do this, make it really obscure like this: `int main(int const argc, char const* const argv<:const:>)` ;-)